# get the relevant information against the object value in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Explanation** :
`A` , `B` , `C` object have values. I have to match only those values with  `dic.data` objects name. if its not match the then get the exception "No error found". see the `Expected_output`.
`A` `B` `C`  get the relvant information.

I am using `lookup` to get `dic` data.

**Note** this should be handle dynamically.  `A` `B` `C` values may differ, that impact on `Expected_output`

```
{
  "_id": {
    "A": "31",
    "B": "40",
    "C": "7"
  },
  "dic": [
    {
      "_id": "5487",
      "data": {
        "A": {
          "31": {
            "name": "NoFile"
          },
          "32": {
            "name": " -- "
          }
        },
        "B": {
          "40": {
            "label": "Label",
            "description": "Error1"
          },
          "41": {
            "label": " Data collection ",
            "description": "error"
          }
        },
        "C": {
          "4": {
            "description": "High problem"
          },
          "7": {
            "description": " Normal"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```
  "Expected_output": {
    "A": {
 "name" :"NoFile",
 "code" : "31"
},
    "B":{
 "label" : "Label",
 "description" : "Error1",
 "code" : "40"

},
    "C": {
 "description" : "Normal",
  "code" : "7"
} 
  }
```

Comment: what if there are multiple elements in `dic` array? and what if it found match in both element?

Comment: thanks for correction, its not possible there are multiple elements , I just update the document

Comment: it is ok to select first element from `dic` array?

Comment: yes its fine but then we have to make a condition with `A` `B`  `C`

Comment: thanks for providing the playground, but how we can manage the exception in that case if nothing match ? with `A`  `B`  `C` .  can we write an exception? if nothing match "Not Found"

Comment: see updated answer, you can set default value in inivialValue of $reduce property.

Comment: i just update the final `expected_out` could you please review it, it's just a minor update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from `dic` array
- `$objectToArray` convert `A` object to array
- `$reduce` to iterate loop of element above converted array and check condition if `_id.A` matches with data `A` then return specific field,
- do the same process for `B` and `C`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      dic: { $arrayElemAt: ["$dic", 0] }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      dic: {
        A: {
          $reduce: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$dic.data.A" },
            initialValue: "Not Found",
            in: {
              $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$$this.k", "$_id.A"] },
                "$$this.v.name",
                "$$value"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        B: {
          $reduce: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$dic.data.B" },
            initialValue: "Not Found",
            in: {
              $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$$this.k", "$_id.B"] },
                "$$this.v.description",
                "$$value"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        C: {
          $reduce: {
            input: { $objectToArray: "$dic.data.C" },
            initialValue: "Not Found",
            in: {
              $cond: [
                { $eq: ["$$this.k", "$_id.C"] },
                "$$this.v.description",
                "$$value"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/35_igUELVh1)